# SSL setup using digital certificates

Tags: ssl, certificates

I started to read about ssl and its certificates and I can't imagine one thing. SSL provides two types of digital certificates: Self-Signed and created by trusted CA. The question is in your opinion Self-Signed certificate is lower or higher to maintenance for **trusted party**? I expect that is lower to maintenance for **trusting party** because of no trusted trusted CA certyficate to maintain.

Someone from you could explain it to me on examples?

Comment: Inbound traffic (to Salesforce) is already secured for most scenarios. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: What is your use case for certs?  Sounds like you're doing integration if I had to guess.  I've encountered this with a middleware platform, and it was easier in that case to just manage with a self signed because updating the CAs was a manual process for each app.

Comment: Do not have any example of use, I just saw the discussion about it somewhere so I wanted to get it clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Self Signed Certificates are lower to maintenance or we can say it has no maintenance cost. Self Signed Certificate is normally used for development or testing purpose. Developer can create self signed certificate from respective development tool.

In Salesforce also we can create self signed certificate but before moving changes to production we have to get third party CA certificate. This is normally used in case of custom domain for customer portal. Third party CA need to renewed every year so it will be higher in maintenance over self signed.

CA Signed Certificate has lot of benefit over self signed certificates. Some of benefits are

1. No Browser Warnings
2. Revoke certificate Any time
3. Increased Customer Trust
4. Well Authenticated Requests

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you're referring to some form of web service and not browser certificates.

Most stacks/browsers/operating systems already manage the CAs for you so it's not much maintenance.  In cases where you don't have a system that keeps the CA list updated then yes, it'd be the same amount of maintenance to change a cert out.

Most systems handle this all for you though and having a CA act as the signing authority allows you to change/update the cert on one side without having to make changes in both systems.  Without a CA in that case you'd have to install the private key into system 1 and the public key into system 2.